# Which user is the owner of git updated files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have created a PHP script that executes a batch file on a Windows server when called. The Windows server will be running Apache and MySQL. Because my knowledge of Apache on a Windows server is limited I am wondering which user will be the owner of the through git updated files.

The batch script that is executed using the webhook looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set FOLDER="C:\WAMP\www\httpdocs"
set MYHOST="localhost"
set MYUSER="change_to_mysql_username"
set MYPASS="change_to_mysql_password"
set MYBASE="change_to_mysql_database_name"

cd %FOLDER%
call git stash save --keep-index
call git pull origin master > version\pull.txt
call git stash drop
call mysql -h %MYHOST% -u %MYUSER% --password=%MYPASS% %MYBASE% < version\dump.sql
exit
```

Comment: Did you run the code and check to see who has ownership of the files?  That seems like the easiest solution to your problem.

Comment: That would be best, but as I am writing a pre-manual without being able to test it on Windows server (just regular windows that doesnt mind any ownerships etc), I hope that someone will know. This pre-manual needs to be submitted before implementation will occur, so I want to be thorough with telling all pro's and con's

Comment: You think NT permissions work differently from Windows 7 to Windows Server versions?

Comment: Yes they do. When running it on my local PC, it will have the regular ownership. In my case SYSTEM, Alvin and Administrators. On Linux it will get the ownership www-data (Apache) as it's done through http. So I am wondering what will be the owner/user of the pulled files from git. Will it have the ownership of www-data (or any other Apache related user) or the ownership of the person who does the initial pull (like the administrator at the screen)